# @babel/typescript doesn't throw errors while webpack build

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, compiler-errors, babeljs

I am trying to transpile TypeScript with Babel 7's @babel/typescript preset. It works fine but for some reason, there aren't any error messages from TS in the build console.

I have the next config:

webpack.config.js

```
const outputPath = require('path').resolve(__dirname, './production');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  entry: [
    './src/index.tsx'
  ],

  output: {
    path: outputPath,
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        enforce: "pre"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'})
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: outputPath
  }
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./production/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

And output is:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/me/projects/react/production
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 1186927fe343142edc70
Version: webpack 4.29.3
Time: 1120ms
Built at: 2019-02-13 19:41:10
                       Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                  index.html  433 bytes          [emitted]  
main.3bb79f4b9e2925734f50.js   1.64 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.3bb79f4b9e2925734f50.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.tsx 40 bytes {main} [built]
...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

It says that there aren't any errors. But there are TS errors in the code.

If I change babel-loader to ts-loader, I will have:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/me/projects/react/production
✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 90ec6ae13f842d672d2d
Version: webpack 4.29.3
Time: 1941ms
Built at: 2019-02-13 19:42:35
                       Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                  index.html  433 bytes          [emitted]  
main.90f2073400581ecd9e5b.js   1.59 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.90f2073400581ecd9e5b.js

...

ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/src/actions/index.ts
./src/actions/index.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/src/actions/index.ts(3,28)
      TS7006: Parameter 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/src/actions/index.ts
./src/actions/index.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/src/actions/index.ts(3,34)
      TS7019: Rest parameter 'argNames' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.

...

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

So, ts-loader shows the errors.

How can I enable errors throwing for @babel/typescript?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As far as I understand, the Babel team disabled type checking while development:

https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel

> How does Babel handle TypeScript code? It removes it.
>
> Yep, it strips out all the TypeScript, turns it into “regular”
>   JavaScript, and continues on its merry way.

But there is a workaround with [fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin)

Just install it as a dependency

```
npm install --save-dev fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
```

And update your webpack config:

```
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

const webpackConfig = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()
  ]
};
```

After that, you will have static type checking running in a separate process, which is fantastic due to it speeds up you build dramatically.

Comment: workaround is great, and barely affects build time.